# Django conditional template tag library loader

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django app that provides templates with optional functionality if certain other apps are available.

It's not possible to load an unavailable template tag library using the standard `{% load %}` Django tag. Trying to do that results in a `TemplateSyntaxError`.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem? I.E. a conditional tag lib loader so I can do something like this:

`{% load_if_available app_tags %}`

and

`{% if_loaded app_tags %}{% endif %}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a new Django app that does what I wanted. It's called django-friendly-tag-loader and is available from PyPi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-friendly-tag-loader/ and hackable @ https://github.com/ataylor32/django-friendly-tag-loader

It provides 3 template tags: `{% friendly_load %}`, `{% if_has_tag %}` and `{% ifnot_has_tag %}`.

`friendly_load` is almost the same as Django's built-in loader, but it just swallows the `InvalidTemplateLibrary` and carries on to the next library to load.

`if_has_tag`/`ifnot_has_tag` check if the template parser has a certain given tag and then either renders, or ignores a bit of the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#a-quick-overview) and register it. 
You can take some inspiration from the django [load](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L959) templatetag.

The problem is, would you would also have to wrap all the "loaded" templatetags in ifs. One way around it would be to register dummy functions that do nothing (maybe just log something but fail silently) so that the code just works, or even better, create an extra if_module_loaded "module" and skips the code inside. Depends on your use case.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm thinking. Except the part about dummy functions, I don't see how that's feasible.

Nobody has solved this problem yet?